# Ruby: Can't get gem to upgrade from 1.8.23 to 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm just getting started with Ruby on Rails, so I apologize if I'm missing something horribly basic here...

Through some reading (and complaints from Rails), I've seen a lot of recommendations to install Ruby/Gem >v1.9.  I upgraded whatever version Ruby was on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine to v1.9.3, but my version of Gem refuses to upgrade beyond 1.8.23.

The gem executable is labeled `/usr/bin/gem1.9.1`, but when you ask it for its version or dump the environment it returns `1.8.23`.  Rails seems to have installed fine with it as 1.8.23, but whines at me to upgrade whenever I generated a new project.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

$ /usr/bin/gem1.9.1 -v
1.8.23

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/andy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I installed ruby with `sudo apt-get ruby-dev`, which seems to be what folks are saying is correct for Ubuntu.  At one point I tried `sudo apt-get ruby-full`, as recommended by ruby-lang.org but that didn't seem to work either.

I'm trying to make sure I set this up correctly, so I don't get too deep into development and realize I borked my environment from the get-go.  Should I just give up on apt-get and install from source, or is there something else that I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rubygems-update`:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick.  I had come across rubygems-update in my travels, but wasn't sure if that was the right thing.  Thanks!